# XAML Design view stuck in 'snap to grid' view

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Silly question, but I somehow switched the XAML/Design view to 'snap to grid' view and can't seem to get it back to the standard design view, even by resetting VS to default settings. What's the hot-key to get my XAML/design view back to the normal view instead of the grids? Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a series of three toggle buttons in VS2012, at the bottom of the XAML Designer (also called the 'Artboard'), and to the left of the scrollbar below it.  These three toggle buttons will do the following (in order from left to right):

- Show/hide gridlines
- Enable/disable snapping to gridlines
- Enable/disable snapping to snaplines (baselines, alignment margins, and the like)

[image: How to turn off snapping]

These are also described a bit further [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj155186.aspx).  They're settable via Tools -> Options as well.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw that I had a white on white (font vs background thing going), which was messing with my view. I changed the color theme (in Tools -> Options) from light to dark and that helped too. I can see what I am doing now. Thanks